# $f(X)$ and $Y$ have same density. Can $Y$ be written $f(X')$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let's suppose :
$X :\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^p$ with the density $f_X dx^p$ and

$Y : \Omega' \to \mathbb{R}^n$ with the density $f_Y dx^n$

And $f : \mathbb{R}^p \to \mathbb{R^n}$ such as $f(X)$ has density $f_Ydx^n$

Does it exist $X': \Omega' \to \mathbb{R^p}$ with density $f_Xdx^p$ such as $Y = f(X')$?

I tried to use cumulative functions to try to transport the structure of $X$ but no success. Do you have an idea?